# Case insensitive XMLEnumValue in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb

JAXB allows to directly locate Enum instances from XML by using the `@XMLEnum` annotation. 
It seems that JAXB is case-sensitive when it comes to locating value from `@XMLEnumValue`.

But I am facing a problem in which I need to locate Enum instance in a *case-insensitive* manner. Does JAXB in some way provide this functionality?
Without this I am stuck with *manually* locating the Enum constant.

I can use `XMLAdapter` for this, but becomes very tedious to maintain an adapter for each enum created.

EDIT:

> Why do you have to locate the enum in a case-insensitive manner?

Because I am using xml to read configuration for my system and I don't want users to be restricted to fixed case. I hope that answers your question.

```
public class CaseInsensitiveEnumAdapter<E extends Enum<E>> extends XmlAdapter<String, E> {

    private final Class<E> clazz;

    public CaseInsensitiveEnumAdapter(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public E unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return Enum.<E>valueOf(clazz, v.toUpperCase().trim());
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(E v) throws Exception {
        return v.name();
    }
}
```

As I require the `.class` for an enum, I will have to create separate adapters for all enums.

Comment: Why do you have to locate the enum in a case-insensitive manner?

Comment: @JamesB I have updated the post to answer your question.

Comment: If the users are not forced to enter case sensitive data, can you easily identify the enums within the XML text content? If so, you could convert it to upper case before giving it to JAXB.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you can't have a single XMLAdapter for all enum values? Can you post this code?

Comment: @JamesB see the updated post for adapter question.

Comment: I believe this is not possible with JAXB. I guess it is not possible for practical reasons - it would be problematic during marshalling. For an enum: `public enum DayOfWeek {MONDAY}`  Let's say there was an annotation to do ignore case for the enum. This would be fine during unmarshalling, so "MonDAY", "MONDAY", "monday" could all be resolved into DayOfWeek.MONDAY.  When marshalling, there would be a problem into what "version" it would marshal. Maybe an implementation where you provide a value to default for marshalling is possible. But I am not aware of anysolution for this problem in JAXB.

Answer (score 2):

Kind Mr. Narendra,

I came up with a solution based on **regular expressions**.
The idea is to use **pattern restriction** with a regular expression capable of accepting any case combination.
I created an example with an enumeration of three colors: green, red and blue.
The following regular exception would accept both "**GrEEn**" and "**gReeN**" literals as valid values:

```
g|Gr|Re|Ee|En|N
```

Here under the example files:

**Example XML-Schema**

```
<xs:simpleType name="ColorType" final="restriction" >
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="g|Gr|Re|Ee|En|N" />
        <xs:pattern value="r|Re|Ed|D" />
        <xs:pattern value="b|Bl|Lu|Ue|E" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="SomeElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Color" type="ColorType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**XML Case 1**

```
<SomeElement>
    <Color>GreEN</Color>
</SomeElement>
```

**XML Case 2**

```
<SomeElement>
    <Color>gREen</Color>
</SomeElement>
```

**JUnit**

```
public class TestJaxb {

    private static final String GREEN = "GREEN";

    @Test
    public void shouldParseCase1() throws JAXBException, MalformedURLException {
        URL xmlUrl = // Load XML file 1
        SomeElement someElement = parse(xmlUrl, SomeElement.class);
        assertEquals(GREEN, someElement.getColor().toUpperCase());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldParseCase2() throws JAXBException, MalformedURLException {
        URL xmlUrl = // Load XML file 2
        SomeElement someElement = parse(xmlUrl, SomeElement.class);
        assertEquals(GREEN, someElement.getColor().toUpperCase());
    }

    private <T> T parse(URL url, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz).createUnmarshaller();
        return clazz.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(url));
    }
}
```

I realize that this makes it more difficult for the user of your XSD specification to understand which values are allowed in the enumeration, but maybe a comment would be enough for you.

The fact is that there is no other way that I've found to achieve this without actually altering JAXB code.

Hope this helps.

Best regards

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question slightly. The question was about how to implement the `@Xml...` annotated bean to be deserialized from an XML that contains enum values that are in a different case than the actual enum constants.

Comment: Hello @SteffenHarbich in the comments of the question someone already said that is not feasible so I gave another idea to achieve what user really needs which is case insensitive unmarshalling.

Comment: Ok, basically you do a `toUpperCase` which was - at least for me - known to be working. I started the bounty because I thought there might be a new feature or something within the last 5 years the question was initially posted. But unluckily not, it seems.

Comment: Not really, without the pattern in the XSD the XJC compiler would fail unmarshalling when XML input is different in case from hard coded schema version. I think that I could implement such a feature in JAXB but I haven't look into it so I have no idea about the actual complexity. I'm sorry this was more meant to be a work around for OP, didn't even notice the thread date :D Cheers!